# How to use multiple parameters in backboneJS events

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I need to pass the second parameter of the onchange function 
(in this case 'border-radius') that I passed on the range input, this value needs to be passed into the console.log on the javascript.
It already works for the 'value' variable.
The 'value'variable returns an integer as it should, but the cssAttribute variable returns 'Object' instead of the 'border-radius' string

HTML

```
  (...)
  <input type="range" min="0" max="200" onchange="sidebar.setElementAttributes(this.value,'border-radius')">
  (...)
```

JS:

```
 var Sidebar = Backbone.Model.extend({
        setElementAttributes: function(value,cssAttribute)
        {
           this.set({ property: value });
               console.log(cssAttribute); //<- works!
        }
        });

        window.sidebar = new Sidebar;   

        sidebar.on('change:property',function(model,value,cssAttribute)
        {
            console.log(value); // <- works!
            console.log(cssAttribute); //<- doesn't work, value is 'Object' instead border-radius'
        });
```

Comment: please tell me what's wrong with the question instead of downvoting it without answering

Comment: You don't pass `cssAttribute` anywhere, so why do you expect to get it in `change:property`?

Comment: Thanks for taking your time.

The event gets triggered whenever the 'property' variable changes.
That step is working.
on the 'sidebar.on' function im using the parameters value and cssAttribute, value returns an integer (the current slider value).
and cssAttribute returns an empty object, I need it to return have the value 'border-radius' in this case.
check the html 
onchange="sidebar.setElementAttributes(this.value,'border-radius')

the value works, I only need the border-radius now.
Do you understand what I'm trying to do?

Comment: doesn't matter someone already answered thanks for taking your time anyway +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass values from trigger to listener using option argument (2nd) of trigger.

It'll be sent to your listener as third argument.

Code :

```
var Sidebar = Backbone.Model.extend({
    setElementAttributes: function (value, cssAttribute) {
        this.set({
            property: value
        }, {
            cssAttribute: cssAttribute
        });
    }
});

window.sidebar = new Sidebar;

sidebar.on('change:property', function (model, value, options) {
    console.log(options.cssAttribute);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W6QTS/)